# Upvoting accepted answer causes checkmark to disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, android-app

On the Stack Exchange Android App version 0.1.23, I upvoted an accepted answer, which caused the checkmark to vanish (as the upvote was highlighted).

Returning to the question later has it displayed correctly.

Comment: For me, the checkmark shows back up after a few seconds. I'm guessing after the voting request has completed, and/or a API refresh?

Comment: you're right. I might have been too impatient to wait for the refresh. it does reappear a few seconds after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next update, thanks.